Entity Framework - Explicit column ordering with object inheritance
I have a BaseEntity class which includes common fields for all entities where I have specified the column order:
public class BaseEntity
{
   [Column(Order = 0)]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   
   [Column(Order = 1)]
   public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

   [Column(Order = 2)]
   public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }

   // other properties
}

I also in some cases need some CreatedBy and UpdatedBy fields, so I have this derived class:
public class TraceableEntity : BaseEntity
{
   
   [Column(Order = 3)]
   public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }

   [Column(Order = 4)]
   public string? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

My entities are derived from either the BaseEntity or the TraceableEntity class, depending on the level of traceability required.
The issue is that when creating migrations EF seemingly ignores the column ordering when there is object inheritance involved. In the DbContextModelSnapshot, I can see that the column orderings are taken into account, but they seem to follow the inheritance order instead of numerical order. Result is that the CreatedBy/UpdatedBy columns appear as column 1 and 2, followed by any other properties, and the CreatedOn etc show up last.
Is there a way to fix this without manually editing the DbContextModelSnapshot or re-order the columns?

Fix what? The column order doesn't matter. If you want a specific CREATE TABLE statement the best option is to create it yourself. Migrations, in any ORM, are essentially a convenience feature and only cover basic features

@PanagiotisKanavos Surely you must see the convenience of having predictable table column patterns for debugging purposes.

No. The query is generated by EF and maps properties to columns by name, never by position. Databases aren't spreadsheets. The column order matters only during display, where Order can have an effect if the UI element uses it. ColumnAttribute isn't specific to Entity Framework, it's part of the DataAnnotations namespace that's used to annotate classes for data binding (among other things)

Unless you use SELECT * and expect the columns to appear in a specific order? That's not the case and is actually one of the main reasons SELECT * is a bad practice. Imagine a UNION query with SELECT * clauses. It's very easy to end up returning the wrong columns. Another reason is that SELECT * can return more or less columns than expected, resulting in query or mapping errors. Finally, EF never uses SELECT *, it always specifies the columns.

Surely you must see the convenience of having predictable table column patterns for debugging purposes - what does it mean? What convenience?

Try to remove all these Column attributes and leave it to EF. You'll probably be more satisfied.
